# Visual Studio (Windows): On test finished

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

So what I'm trying to do is to write a script that gets triggered whenever I test my project inside VS 2019. I would like to then display this result externally (on another device).

I believe I need to write an extension, but have no idea how I should subscribe to that event.

Comment: Did you want to execute the script after the debug process?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT No, I'd pretty much like it to fire whenever I manually hit "Run all tests" in the test explorer. It would be nice if it also did this whenever I run a single test, but that's just a nice to have.